# "exam supervisor" or "exam superintendent"?

Tags: word-choice

> 1.He has a duty of an exam **supervisor**.
>
> 2.He has a duty of an exam **superintendent**.

Which word is suitable for exam, supervisor or superintendent?

Comment: As an aside, "He has a duty of a" isn't quite the correct use of articles.  Because it's a specific duty, it would sound more fluent to say "He has **the** duty", and *duty* usually refers to an action, like "**being** exam supervisor": He has **the** duty of **being** exam supervisor.

Comment: These would be considered functional titles in an organization, therefore either one could be correct. In reality, "superintendent" is more likely an upper manager, and probably not responsible for supervising exams.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "exam supervisor" but "exam superintendent" is not so good. Superintendent is someone who has a high post in police department or in an organization. It is also used to refer to caretaker of a building. So it is not appropriate to refer to a teacher or someone like that who comes to see the students in exam.

You can also refer to such a person  as "invigilator".

Comment: *invigilator* is virtually unknown in the US; cisAtlantically we tend to use 'proctor'.